# extraer numeros pares de una lista conservando su orden en python

Tags: python

debo crear una función que extraiga números pares de una lista L, y en caso de no tener ninguno, retornar una lista vacía. He intentado esto:

```
def extraePares(l): 
    lista = [l]
    for x in lista:
        if x % 2 == 0:
            print [x]
print(extraePares([1,0,-4,-5,2,0]))
print(extraePares([]))
print(extraePares([0]))
print(extraePares([3,1]))
print(extraePares([2,4,2]))
```

cuál es el error?

Comment: Puedes resumir el cuerpo de tu función a una sola línea `return [i for i in l if i % 2 == 0]`. Alternativamente, modifica tu código [a esto](https://www.online-python.com/KEeafBspD4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que quieres recibe una lista y debe devolver otra en la que guardas los datos.

En tu primera linea creas una lista de listas, así que `x` no es un número, es una lista completa.

```
def extraePares(lista_que_recibe_la_funcion:list):
    #   Crear una nueva lista vacia para guardar los datos
    lista_respuesta = []

    for numero in lista_que_recibe_la_funcion:
        if numero % 2 == 0:
            #   Añade el valor a la nueva lista
            lista_respuesta.append(numero)

    return lista_respuesta




print(extraePares([1,0,-4,-5,2,0]))
print(extraePares([]))
print(extraePares([0]))
print(extraePares([3,1]))
print(extraePares([2,4,2]))
```